# How to move in a big jump on the bash shell?

Tags: bash

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> bring you to the beginning and end of the command line.

How do you jump to the middle? or at least 20 chars or so?

If any of you use bash a lot and type quickly, you end up 'flicking' back and forth from beginning to end quickly.

I'd like to jump really quickly (another control combo w/o loss of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> ability as one example) to an approximate middle vs holding the <kbd>Right</kbd> or <kbd>Left</kbd> key down and waiting or needing to jump into vi mode.

Comment: a comment, since I can't find a definitive answer.  Check the output of `bind -l`, and try to find what those those keywords do. There's one 'vi-column' that looks interesting. or try the "forward-word" (ESC-f) backwards-word (ESC-b) tags.

Comment: @Rich - Thanks! bind 'Control-g:backward-word' and bind 'Control-f:forward-word' approximates the behavior. Kind of: The least typing w/o needing to switch to vi/emacs modes

Comment: Not sure about *nix but on OSX bash, you can use `ALT`+`<-` (left arrow) or `ALT`+`->` (right arrow) to move between non-characters/numbers. This works in AWS Linux too. Also don't forget `CTRL`+`u` and `CTRL`+`k` for delete from cursor to left/right margins respectively and `CTRL`+`w` for deleting (backspace) one "word" which is defined as spaces.

Answer (score 2):

If you set command line editing to vi mode:

```
set -o vi
```

Then you can (for example) move position to 20 characters from the start of the line by:

- pressing `ESC` key
- press `^` (to get to start of line)
- press `20l`  (moves cursor 20 characters to the right)

Comment: ctrl-a and ctrl-e are emacs/gmacs commands.  you're asking them to switch.

Comment: Yes, this is an answer. I edit my question to get more specific.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for an Emacs Key mode method,

Use alt-# then the command.

For instance, Alt-3 Alt-b  will move cursor back three whole words.

[Reference](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/bash-emacs-editing-mode-cheat-sheet/)

Answer (score 0):

This answer depends on the nature of the line (i.e. if it's big block of text or individual words) and the terminal emulator used.

If it's individual words, I tend to use ctrl + [left or right arrow key] to hop across words when in mintty.

If in putty, I can do the equivalent with alt+f and alt+b to navigate forwards and backwards across words respectively.